# Finding subgroups of a group from specific order

Tags: group-theory, problem-solving

Given the following group:

$$ \left<\left\{ \begin{bmatrix}a & b \\0 & c \end{bmatrix}  \mid a,b,c\in \Bbb Z_{5},a,c  \neq 0  \right\} ,\:\:   *  \right> $$

where ∗ is multiplication.

How many sub-groups from order 2 and order 5 has here?

Which theorem I can use here to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are $a,b,c$ supposed to be elements of $\Bbb{Z}_5$ instead of $\Bbb{Z}^5$? I'm fairly sure that has to be the case - just checking :-) If you have trouble with TeX, just ask!

Comment: And for your question to be received well it is recommended that you explain what you have tried. Here's a suggestion. A subgroup of order two must be generated by a matrix $A$ such that $A^2$ is the identity matrix. You could first try and solve the problem: for which choices of $a,b,c$ do you get
$$\pmatrix{a&b\cr0&c\cr}^2=I?$$

Comment: You're right, I fixed that.

Comment: The solution is: a=c=1,  b=0. But how's that help me ?

Comment: Is that the only solution?

Comment: No, because this is mod 5.

Comment: The reason why it helps is that a subgroup of a prime order $p$ is always cyclic, and consists of powers of the generator(there should be exactly $p$ distinct powers).

Comment: With $a=c=1, b=0$ you get a matrix of order $1$, which does not help you.

Comment: Something is still missing for me, to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

If $\pmatrix{a&b\cr0&c\cr}^2=I$ then 
$$a=4, c=4, b=0$$
$$a=4, c=1, b=0,1,2,3,4$$
$$a=1, c=4, b=0,1,2,3,4$$
therefor this group has $11$ subgroup of order $2$ and if $\pmatrix{a&b\cr0&c\cr}^5=I$ then $$a=c=1, b=1,2,3,4$$ thus this group has $4$ subgroup of order $5$.

Comment: Order 5 or 4 ? I am asked about order 5.

Comment: You intended to 4 subgroup of order 5 ?

Comment: Excuse me, i mistake.

Comment: Could you tell me how did you get the solution ?

Comment: Agree with the tally of order two subgroups. Each such subgroup has a single element of order two. OTOH a subgroup of order five has four distinct elements of order five, so you are overcounting those. Hint: Which elements belong to the subgroup generated by the matrix with $a=c=b=1$?